# How can I add pattern that start with hash to gitignore

Tags: git, emacs, gitignore, temporary-files

When I work with Emacs it create temporary files like `#foo.txt#` how can I add pattern to `.gitignore` that will ignore those files (# is interpreted by git as comment in .gitignore)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try escaping the `#` character:

```
$ cat .gitignore
\#*.txt\#
```

I hope this helps.